# Which markup language is this?

Tags: wiki, markup, wiki-markup

We are using a kind of markup language like this:

```
* Head1

 some text here (paragraph)

  ** Head 2
```

And for bold we are using this:

```
<<<boldtext>>>
```

For listing from a to z we are using:

```
 [[a]] some texts of list

 [[a]] some other texts of list
```

Tables are like this:

```
 *----------+--------------+----------------+
| <<Column Title>> | <<Column Title>> | <<Column Title>> |
*----------+--------------+----------------+
| Content1 | Content2 | Content3  |
*----------+--------------+----------------+
```

Because I need to know more about this markup language I am so curious which language it is?

Comment: You may have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_document_markup_languages

Comment: @JamesSharp Thanks! I found it out, the markup language is Doxia. Doxia is not on the wiki page. But thank you all the same:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: It is Doxia.

Here is a link as reference: http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/apt-format.html